# Continuous function with $f(x)=f(2x)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $T$ be the family of continuous functions on $(0,\infty)$ defined by 
>   $$T=\{f\colon(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R} \mid \text{$f(x)=f(2x)$ for all $x \in (0,\infty)$}\}.$$

For each of the following statements , state whether it is true or false

> a) Any element $f\in T$ is bounded
>
> b) Any element $f\in T$ is uniformly continuous
>
> c) Any element $f\in T$ is differentiable
>
> d) Any uniformly bounded sequence in $T$ has a uniformly converging subsequence

---

I think that using simple iteration, we have $f(\frac{x}{2})=f(x)=\cdots =f\big(\frac{x}{2^n}\big)$.

Now since $f$ is continuous, so taking both side limit can i thnk right way...

Comment: I agree with you, the iteration is a good way to go.

Comment: but how come to conclusion

Comment: Note that a function in $T$ is completely specified by its behaviour on $[1,2]$. Conversely, any continuous function $f:[1,2]\to\Bbb R$ can be extended to a function in $T$, provided $f(1)=f(2)$. Given these facts, (a) and (c) are easy. (d) is just a question of finding a rather obvious counter-example. And for (b), we have that _no_ function in $T$ is uniformly continuous, except the function that is identically zero.

Comment: Consider the composition of such functions with the exponent. The resulting function is $ln(2)$-periodic.

Comment: @TonyK - where did that claim for (b) come from? For starters, all constant functions are in $T$, and they are all uniformly continuous, not just $9$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: Sorry, you are right of course. I should have said that the only uniformly continuous functions are the constant functions.